# Unexplained Django error. Diagnosis anyone?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project I keep on github. It worked perfectly fine on my laptop. I downloaded it on my desktop and tried to "python manage.py runserver" or even "python manage.py shell"
I get a

```
Error: No module named messages
```

No other messages, no stack trace, nothing..Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have come across similar errors a number of times. They have been the result of python not being able to find the django or project files in the path. This is exceptionally annoying when django gets installed or referenced to one version of python when you have multiple python installs on the machine. It may help to explicitly choose which python version you are using, ie `python2.5 manage.py runserver` or `python2.6 manage.py runserver`.

Make sure you have your project in your PYTHONPATH.